# PHP - Remove DOTs from text but exclude numbers

Tags: php, regex

I want remove dots (`.`) in a string containing `numbers` and `text`.

Ex: `S.D.M.S` to `SDMS`

But I want to leave the (`.`) in `numbers` as it is.

Ex: `123.50` to `123.50`

I tried `str_replace()`, but it removed all (`.`)s

How can I do it in `PHP`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `preg_replace`:

```
$result = preg_replace('/(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)/', '', $string);
```

where

- `(?<!\d)` is a negative lookbehind, assumes there's no digit before the dot.
- `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead, assumes there's no digit after the dot.

Comment: Dude I really need to learn RegEx. Can you hand us some tutorials or courses?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes me too

Comment: @PhiterFernandes: This site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/